# Asking With Login PHP Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am new to this PHP login script stuff but I do want to learn.

I have **dbconect.php** like this:

```
<?php
//core
function dbcon(){
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $db = "test";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    $select = mysqli_select_db($connect,$db);
}

function host(){
    $h = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/test/";
    return $h;
}

function hRoot(){
    $url = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/test/";
    return $url;
}

//parse string
function gstr(){
    $qstr = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    parse_str($qstr,$dstr);
    return $dstr;
}

?>
```

And i do have **login.php** like this:

```
 <?php
    include('admin/lib/dbcon.php');
    dbcon(); 
    session_start();    
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    /*................................................ admin .....................................................*/
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,$query)or die(mysqli_error($connect));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    /*...................................................Technical Staff ..............................................*/
    $query_client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result_client = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM client WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'")or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    $num_row_client = mysqli_num_rows($query_client);
    $row_client = mysqli_fetch_array($query_client);

    if( $num_row > 0 ) { 
    $_SESSION['id']=$row['admin_id'];
    echo 'true_admin';

    mysqli_query($connect, "insert into user_log (username,login_date,admin_id)values('$username',NOW(),".$row['admin_id'].")")or die(mysqli_error($connect));

    }else if ($num_row_client > 0){
    $_SESSION['client']=$row_client['client_id'];
    echo 'true';

    mysqli_query($connect, "insert into user_log (username,login_date,client_id)values('$username',NOW(),".$row_client['client_id'].")")or die(mysqli_error($connect));

     }else{ 
            echo 'false';
    }    

    ?>
```

I also had made the table SQL

The question is: What is wrong so i can not login using those code?

very appreciate with all the answer

thank you very much

Comment: What error message is it throwing?

Comment: No error message just cant login

Comment: make sure you have php display errors function enabled because if it isn't then it doesnot show errors just blank screen. 
And your login function might not work because you have define $connect in your dbconnect file inside a function so it is local to that function only you won't be able to use that on the whole page. so, might be that when you run the query it doesnt take the $connect value.
so firstly check if display errors are enabled and paste them here if it displays any error.

Answer (score 0):

/*...................................................Try This ..............................................*/

```
$query_client = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result_client = mysqli_query($connect, $query_client);   //pass your method here rather than duplicate query
$num_row_client = mysqli_num_rows($query_client);
$row_client = mysqli_fetch_array($query_client);

if( $num_row > 0 ) { 
$_SESSION['id']=$row['admin_id'];
echo 'true_admin';

mysqli_query($connect, "insert into user_log (username,login_date,admin_id)values('$username',NOW(),".$row['admin_id'].")")or die(mysqli_error($connect));

}else if ($num_row_client > 0){
$_SESSION['client']=$row_client['client_id'];
echo 'true';

mysqli_query($connect, "insert into user_log (username,login_date,client_id)values('$username',NOW(),".$row_client['client_id'].")")or die(mysqli_error($connect));

 }else{ 
        echo 'false';
}
```